# How to set enum variant's fields to default values without assigning each individually?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have an enum where each variant can have its own unique fields:

```rust
enum X {
    A { pa: bool, pb: u8, pc: u32, pd: u32 },
    B { pc: bool, pd: u8, pe: bool, pf: bool },
}
```

I don't want define a default value for the type `X` itself using `#[derive(Default)]`. Rather, I want to assign a variable to a variant and have the variant's fields set the default values.

For example, if choosing `X::A`, have the equivalent of the following without listing each field separately?

```rust
let xa = X::A { pa: bool::default(), pb: u8::default(), pc: u32::default(), pd: u32::default() };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create constructors so that you don't need to write it out each time.

```rs
impl X {
    pub fn a() -> Self {
        Self::A {
            pa: bool::default(),
            pb: u8::default(),
            pc: u32::default(),
            pd: u32::default(),
        }
    }
    pub fn b() -> Self {
        Self::B {
            pc: bool::default(),
            pd: u8::default(),
            pe: bool::default(),
            pf: bool::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

And then call them like `X::a()`. You could also make constants, but you would need to construct the constants with const functions or literals.

This is about the limit to what you can do with struct-like enum variants. They aren't very ergonomic, so not-so-coincidentally, the most common way to write complex variants is with a real struct instead.

```rs
pub enum X {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct A {
    pub pa: bool,
    pub pb: u8,
    pub pc: u32,
    pub pd: u32,
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct B {
    pub pc: bool,
    pub pd: u8,
    pub pe: bool,
    pub pf: bool,
}

impl X {
    pub fn a() -> Self {
        Self::A(A::default())
    }
    pub fn b() -> Self {
        Self::B(B::default())
    }
}
```

These allow you to derive default implementations for the contents of each variant, as well as making it easier to construct and deconstruct the enum.

Comment: Additionally with the second version, the struct-update syntax - `X::A(A { ..A::default() })` - becomes possible so you can get default values with the ability to override fields as well.